# Load data from two (or more) files into one table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have one table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  x INT NOT NULL,
  y INT NOT NULL );
```

The data is in two files: One file has `(id, x)` value pairs and another file has `(id, y)` value pairs. There are about 20 million rows in each. Most of the `id` values that appear in the `x` file also appear in the `y` file and visa versa.

Can you suggest how to load the `id`, `x` and `y` values from the two files into `t`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a unix machine you may have access to "join" which can join your 2 files together and produce them on stdout.  Bulk load the standard out directly into mysql. This will reduce the number of writes to disk.

Comment: That is interesting. I'll give it a try. Btw: according to the man page, join(1) requires the input files to be sort(1)ed by key column.

Comment: @fsb, I used to do a lot of ssh/gzip/dump/load to and from a colocation. You certainly can load the 2 files into mysql then join them into another table.  I like using pipes to reduce disk io though, however it likely is irrelevant.

Comment: join(1) replies on sort(1) having gotten both tables in order first. That's OK so long as sort(1) produces the same order as MySQL would, which is true in this case since we sort by a unique INT. But if you sort strings, sort(1) doesn't generally use the same collation rules as MySQL so join(1) will produce different result than JOIN in MySQL. It's just something worth noting.

Comment: @fsb, Thanks for the update.  How did MySQL's sort order differing from sort(1)'s affect you?

Comment: Like I said, the sort order in this case was the same in sort(1) and in MySQL so there was no problem. I just added the comment so that others who read this conversation in future will be aware of the difference in MySQL's sorting of strings vs. sort(1).

Answer (score 0):

Load each of the files into two separate tables using LOAD DATA INFILE. Then use INSERT INTO ... SELECT to insert data into table t.

Comment: If one table has a row with `(id=23, x=55)` and the other has a row with `(id=23, y=126)`, I need to end up with a row `(id=23, x=55, y=126)` in `t`. Inserting the first into `t` is straightforward. But on inserting from the second there will be duplicate keys. Does INSERT INTO SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE y=... work for this?

Comment: No it doesn't, but you can do full outer join in your SELECT (unfortuantely that's a bit of a work by UNIONing a RIGHT and LEFT join since MySQL doesn't have support for FULL OUTER join syntax yet)

Comment: I don't follow your suggestion about UNION. Nor do I understand why, if `t.id` is `t`’s primary key, `INSERT INTO t (id, y) SELECT tt.key, tt.val FROM tmptbl ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE y=tt.val;` would not work, assuming `tmptbl(key,val)` is the temporary table I loaded the data file into.

Comment: Indeed. I checked again, and INSERT INTO .. SELECT does suppost ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause. Somehow I thought I doesn't. Less problems for you. ;)

Comment: Hi Mchl, If you edit your answer to mention the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE then I'll accept it.